# VSCode keep coming with the error of Invalid string length when trying to run a command

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I was ssh remote to a host to do the development. But when I try to run some command for example `Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace`, VSCode keep coming up with the error below:

```
Command 'Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace' resulted in an error (Invalid string length)
```

There is no much useful information in the output log, anyone know what's going on here.

Thanks

Comment: Please file a report in [github/vscode-java](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues).